# How do I return NULL if no regex match found in a character vector element?

Tags: r, regex

I have a character vector which looks like(`dput` output):

```
c("           genotype[0]= rv props(rr,rv,vv)=  0.000  0.944  0.056    reads=     10 , variants=      7", 
"           genotype[1]= na ", "           genotype[2]= rv props(rr,rv,vv)=  0.000  1.000  0.000    reads=     16 , variants=      8", 
"           genotype[3]= rv props(rr,rv,vv)=  0.001  0.999  0.000    reads=     13 , variants=      5", 
"           genotype[4]= vv props(rr,rv,vv)=  0.000  0.489  0.511    reads=     10 , variants=      8", 
"           genotype[5]= vv props(rr,rv,vv)=  0.000  0.051  0.949    reads=     10 , variants=      9", 
"           genotype[6]= rr props(rr,rv,vv)=  1.000  0.000  0.000    reads=     20 , variants=      0", 
"           genotype[7]= rv props(rr,rv,vv)=  0.000  1.000  0.000    reads=     15 , variants=      7", 
"           genotype[8]= rr props(rr,rv,vv)=  0.975  0.025  0.000    reads=      7 , variants=      0", 
"           genotype[9]= vv props(rr,rv,vv)=  0.000  0.001  0.999    reads=     17 , variants=     16"
)
```

I'd like to return the second value in the triplet of probabilities for each character vector, i.e. 0.944, 0.999 etc. However, I also want `NULL` or something else in the result to indicate that line starting with `genotype[1]` had no match.

My code looks like this:

```
regmatches(genotype_strings, regexpr("[[:digit:]].[[:digit:]]+  [[:digit:]].[[:digit:]]+  [[:digit:]].[[:digit:]]+", genotype_strings))
```

Though the result has only 9 elements, while I'd like to have 10.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all characters except digits, dots and spaces. Then we can read it in using `read.table`.  Extract the third field.

```
read.table(text = gsub("[^0-9. ]", "", v), fill = TRUE)[, 3]
##  [1] 0.944    NA 1.000 0.999 0.489 0.051 0.000 1.000 0.025 0.001
```